# golang templates processing and generics

Tags: templates, go

I have two golang html templates, as follows:

```
var m map[string]string
m = make(map[string]string)

m["First"] = `<html>
<body>First template type {{.First}}
</html>`

m["Second"] = `<html>
<body>Second template type {{.SecondF1}} {{.SecondF2}}
</html>`
```

The first html template takes only one argument, named `First` whereas the second template needs two arguments, named `SecondF1` and `SecondF2`.

Now I have a struct which has two fields, one for receiving a template name and another for receiving the template arguments.

```
type tmplReceiver struct {
    TmplName string
    TmplArgs string // Receives JSON string
}
```

Now, examples of instances for the above structs could be:

```
var i, j tmplReceiver

i.TmplName = "First"
i.TmplArgs = `{"Field1": "First Template Argument"}`

j.TmplName = "Second"
j.TmplArgs = `{
  "SecondF1": "Second template First Argument", 
  "SecondF2": "Second template Second Argument"
}`
```

Now I can get the Template string by using the map, for example:

```
tmplStr := m[i.TmplName] (or)
tmplStr := m[j.TmplName]

tmpl, _ = template.New("email").Parse(tmplStr)
```

However, how do I get the template to be executed for all the possible template types, with a single `tmpl.Execute` statement. In other words, if I want to have the following code:

```
var buff bytes.Buffer
if err := tmpl.Execute(&buff, tmplPtr); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Println(buff.String())
```

How do I get the `tmplPtr` to be valid, irrespective of how many templates I have (`First`, `Second`, etc.) and each of these templates can have a variable number of arguments (`First` has only one arg, whereas `Second` has two args, etc.)

I do not want to write N different `tmpl.Execute` statements with an `if` block for each template name. Is there any other alternative approach to solve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `json.Unmarshal` nor `template.Execute` cares about the actual type of the data, this will all be handled at runtime. So you can just parse the json to an `interface{}` and pass that to your templates. Provided that the json data contains the fields that are expected by the template to which you pass the data, this will just work fine.

[Playground link](https://play.golang.com/p/99GmCMdr3K)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

var templates = map[string]*template.Template{
    "A": template.Must(template.New("A").Parse("{{ .A }}")),
    "B": template.Must(template.New("B").Parse("{{ .B }} and {{ .C.D }}")),
}

type tmplReceiver struct {
    TmplName string
    TmplArgs string
}

func main() {
    receivers := []tmplReceiver{
        tmplReceiver{"A", `{"A": "Value for A"}`},
        tmplReceiver{"B", `{"B": "Value for B", "C": { "D": "Value for D" }}`},
    }

    for _, receiver := range receivers {
        var data interface{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(receiver.TmplArgs), &data)

        var buffer bytes.Buffer
        templates[receiver.TmplName].Execute(&buffer, data)
        fmt.Println(buffer.String())
    }
}
```

Which prints

> Value for A
>
> Value for B and Value for D

Comment: But I want this as part of a HTTP handler where the input will be coming from other languages too. So I need a JSON-able struct with no interfaces or maps.

Comment: @SankarP I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but in my updated answer you can handle any incoming json, no matter what the structure, and use it in your templates. The only requirement is that the data contains the fields that you want to use in your template, but one cannot avoid that anyway.